# "Unhashable type: set" when trying to update an existing set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Not much to explain here, I'm trying to recursively get a set of all the subclasses of a class:

```
@classmethod
def get_subclasses(cls):
    subclasses = set(cls.__subclasses__())
    subclasses.update(sub.get_subclasses() for sub in subclasses)
    return subclasses
```

It raises an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` from the `.update()` line.

Why? How to "fix"?

Comment: You're trying to put sets inside sets, which can't be done (for the reason given - sets aren't hashable). Try `for sub in subclasses: subclasses.update(sub.get_subclasses())`.

Comment: Also, you're updating the collection while iterating it. That seems like a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add sets to your set. Sets can only be populated with hashable types - set is not one of those (it is a mutable type, which shouldn't really be hashable - you can't use lists for the same reason - though you can use tuples).

Anyway, I think the intentions and you code might not be aligned...

If I understand your intention you might be better writing this longhand:

```
subclasses = set()
for parent_sub in set(cls.__subclasses__()):
    subclasses.add(parent_sub)
    for child_sub in parent_sub.get_subclasses():
        subclasses.add(child_sub)

return subclasses
```

That, I think, should give you a flat set of all classes in the hierarchy?